# map a function across a list, but with different function inputs

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I'm looking for a way to map a function over a list, but to be able to give the function different inputs for each iteration.

a simple example would be the following:

```
example_func <- function(a, b, c) {
  z = a + b + c
  return(z)
}

ex_list <- list(5, 14, 32)
```

executing on the first element in the list would look like:

```
example_func(ex_list[[1]], 45, 43)
```

I know I could also:

```
lapply(ex_list, function(x) example_func(x, 45, 43)
```

but that example would use 45 and 43 for each of the iterations in lapply. How could I give it, for example, these three sets of arguments to iterate over the three elements in the list?

```
c(x, 45, 43)
c(x, 3, 33)
c(x, 23, 22)
```

Or another similar example would be write.csv(), which takes the object and then the name of the file to be written.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10, 1000, replace = TRUE))
df_list <- split(df, df$x)
lapply(df_list, function(x) write.csv(x, arg1))...
```

how could I iterate through this list and give the specified names to feed it?

I've done something similar to this before, but it would be a for loop iterating through `seq_along` the list, and then also finding that index within a vector of names. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `tidyverse`, this is a job for `purrr`. With `pmap` function you can iterate through several lists.

```r
example_func <- function(a, b, c) {
  z = a + b + c
  return(z)
}

ex_list <- list(5, 14, 32)
ex_args1 <- list(45, 3, 23)
ex_args2 <- list(43, 33, 22)

library(purrr)       

list(ex_list, ex_args1, ex_args2) %>% pmap(example_func)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 93
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 50
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 77
example_func(ex_list[[1]], ex_args1[[1]], ex_args2[[1]])
#> [1] 93
example_func(ex_list[[2]], ex_args1[[2]], ex_args2[[2]])
#> [1] 50
example_func(ex_list[[3]], ex_args1[[3]], ex_args2[[3]])
#> [1] 77
```

`purrr` package helps you with functionnal programming and iteration. You should look at the [documentation](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/) as it could help you with other task like iteration with `write.csv` using `purrr::walk` for example.

one example using a dataframe to provide the iterating list and matching by named arguments.

```r
example_func <- function(a, b, c) {
  z = a + b + c
  return(z)
}

library(tidyverse)
tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~c,
  5, 45, 43,
  13, 3, 33,
  32, 23, 22
) %>% pmap_dbl(example_func)
#> [1] 93 49 77
```

Comment: awesome thank you, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. last quick Q. What if the first argument of the `example_func` is a dataframe, and I want to keep that dataframe object constant? So instead of `example_func(ex_list[[1]], ex_args1[[1]].. etc`, it would be `example_func(df, ex_args[[1]], ex_args2[[1]]`

Comment: you can provide some fixed argument to `example_func` inside `pmap`. if `example_fun <- function(df, a, b, c)` and you want to iterate through a b and c only, you can do `pmap(example_func, df = mydf)` to fix the `df` arg. Look to the documentation, it is very powerful.

Answer (score 5):

Just put the other values in two other lists, say, `l2` and `l3`. Then use `Map`, that is what it's meant for.

```
ex_list <- list(5, 14, 32)
l2 <- list(45, 3, 23)
l3 <- list(43, 33, 22)

Map(example_func, ex_list, l2, l3)
#[[1]]
#[1] 93
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 50
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 77
```

This can be done for any number of function arguments, each set in its own list.